# DynamoDB TTL not keeping up with flagging, not deleting items fast enough, is there any way to speed it up?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I have a table in DynamoDB with an item being added every 15 seconds (4/min). I now have over 5 GB in this table and I don't need the data past 30 days or so. So, I set up the TTL to start flagging items after 30 days. But, TTL is only deleting about 1 or 2 items per minute, so it won't keep up.

Is there any way to increase TTLs rate of deleting?

Fwiw, my scripts are in python 3.

UPDATE: After flagging many more items for TTL, ~ 100k, the deletion rate has increased to ~ 10/min. While it still likely won't clear them in 48 hours, it looks like it will clear them soon enough. The deletion rate is somewhat proportional to the total number of TTL-expired items - it's just not that precise, I had the same absolute deletion rate with 100 items as with 10,000 items.

Comment: How are you certain about "TTL is only deleting about 1 or 2 items per minute"? You can take a look at the table's CloudWatch metrics to verify this.

Comment: Yes, when I started the TTL, the CloudWatch graph was showing around 1-2 per minute but jumping around a lot. I checked back after 5 days, and it averaged 2.1 items per minute for the full 5 days straight, about 15,000 total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Amazon's documentation, they are targeting roughly 48 hours to delete any objects that have timed out:

> Depending on the size and activity level of a table, the actual delete
> operation of an expired item can vary. Because TTL is meant to be a
> background process, the nature of the capacity used to expire and
> delete items via TTL is variable (but free of charge). TTL typically
> deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration.

Further details can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html

If you have items that are going beyond the "typical" TTL cleanup time after a few days, it would probably warrant an AWS support call.

Comment: Yeah, 48 hours isn't a problem as a lag, it just has to be proportional to the total items to be deleted, i.e. it has to keep up. I had about 15,000 items and it took 5 days, averaging 2.1 items per minute, pretty flat rate, on an hourly average, the whole time. If I'm dumping in 4/minute, either its rate has to speed up or TTL doesn't really work for me.

Comment: I'm curious though, has it roughly kept up over time? The rate of deletion, according to their docs, should correspond to roughly your rate of addition from 30 days ago. Since they give it a 48 hour buffer, can you confirm if you have any objects that are older than 32 days in the table?

Comment: Good question, I didn't see the 30 days thing, so that may explain it. To answer your question, no, there's nothing that's been sitting there for longer than 30 days. I wondered if maybe 15k records wasn't enough to trigger a faster delete rate. So, I started flagging additional items (with another script) to build up the total number.  I now have about 70k items, and am adding about 10x faster than production, and the delete rate has jumped to about 5/min. So, I guess maybe it would catch up, ... eventually?